# Getting connected partitions using METIS

Tags: python, graph, partitioning, metis

I am using [Metis](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) on [Python](https://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to partition a [networkx](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) graph I have. My objective is to get partitions that have an almost equal sum of node weights, which Metis does perfectly. However, a constraint I want to respect is that nodes in the same partition should be connected (have edges in common), which Metis doesn't do. Is there a way or a parameter to ensure that?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the graph and save it in a file, and then call Metis through console using -contig option.